# Fixed-width columns in a dynamic table

Tags: html, css

I have a table that shall be dynamic (which means I cannot use `table-layout: fixed`) but that shall have several fixed-width columns in it. The fixed-width columns shall also support colspans of larger than 1.

The dynamic columns (and the table itself) should work just like normal table cells in pure HTML:

- Data shall never get cut off, even when the viewport is too small
- When the table does not fit the viewport, it shall be wider than the viewport

The fixed-width colums should work like this:

- Always have a fixed width
- Cut off any data that does not fit into it

I tried three approaches, none of them works:

- Defining the widths in the first table row
- Defining the widths in a colgroup/col section of the table
- Inserting a `<div>` into the fixed-width cells

Nothing works.

[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcek6yLq/)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.fw {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="100%">
      <col width="50px">
        <col width="50px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>My dynamic cell shall be greedy and take up all available space</td>
    <td class=fw nowrap>
      <div class=fw>My first fixed-width cell shall be of fixed width</div>
    </td>
    <td class=fw>..</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dynamic</td>
    <td class=fw colspan=2>Fixed cells shall also support multiple colspans</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As I said, I cannot use `table-layout: fixed` because I also have dynamic columns.

Comment: What's wrong with [this example I made](https://jsfiddle.net/enqnpq9h/) with `table-layout: fixed`? 2 columns are fixed at 100px each and the second row includes a colspan that is 200px. The fluid column resizes fine.

Comment: @misterManSam: The .fluid column disappears when the viewport gets too small - I tried to add "min-width: 200px" to .fluid as a workaround but that didn't work either. The .fluid column should work like a normal table cell - it should never overflow or cut off data.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just [place a suitable `min-width` on the table itself](https://jsfiddle.net/5hLxheh0/)?

Comment: @misterManSam: Yeah that seems to work, thanks - Write an answer and I will accept it (after a few tests...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use `table-layout: fixed` if you have a suitable `min-width` placed on the table to prevent overflow of the dynamically sized column:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

#### Example

Note that the `width` attribute is deprecated and the CSS property should be used to size your columns and table.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
}
td {
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fluid {
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="fluid">
    <col class="fixed">
    <col class="fixed">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>My dynamic cell shall be greedy and take up all available space</td>
    <td>My first fixed-width cell shall be of fixed width</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dynamic</td>
    <td colspan="2">Fixed cells shall also support multiple colspans</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
min-width: 50px;
max-width: 50px;
```